# Replacing fragment display a blank screen

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to replace `Fragment` using `FragmentTransaction`.
It works fine but during remplacement, Android displays a blank screen very ugly before displaying the new `Fragment`

Code is :

```
FragmentManager mng = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transac = mng.beginTransaction();
transac.replace(R.id.contentframe, myFragment, CUSTOM_TAG); // replace current fragment by myFragment
transac.commit();
```

After `commit()` call, old fragment disappeared, a blank screen is displayed few milliseconds then new fragment is displayed.

Is anyone know how could I avoid this blank screen to be displayed during the transaction ?

Thanks.

Comment: set custom animations fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations().

Comment: Post your fragments code please.

Comment: My fragment is juste a fragment class with a view ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set custom animations during Transaction.

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.card_flip_right_in,R.anim.card_flip_right_out,R.anim.card_flip_left_in,R.anim.card_flip_left_out);
```

Like this. You can define animations.

Hope it helps

Comment: I don't understand  setCustomAnimations solves this issue why.